# How to change the error "host not found" to my customised message error?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, general-network-error

The problem is I have these messages :

- host not found
- a server with a specified hostname could not be found
- network is not available

Especially the second message it shows for a second and then everything become working

So what I want is to know how to find these msgs and how to handle them and put my message instead of them or just make another action instead of showing them like the facebook app , when the connection down it shows a red alert with label "network error"

How can I do this?

Comment: the model error descriptions arent really ment for display to the enduser. you have to check the error and devise your own error object

Comment: ok but how can i check for the error ?? this is the problem where i can find it so i can control the process

Comment: i have error.code in my webservice response ,, but it doesn't have the errors that i want ,, is it in reachability.m file ??

Comment: what happen..first you accepted my answer and now remove acceptation.. why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the solution and its like this

```
-(void)handleError:(NSError*)error{
SEL onerror = @selector(onerror:);
if(self.action != nil) { onerror = self.action; }
if([self.handler respondsToSelector: onerror]) {
    if (error.code == -1003 || error.code == -1001 || error.code == -1004) { //check all kind of errors
        [self send];
    }else{
    [self.handler performSelector: onerror withObject: error];
    }
} else {
    if(self.defaultHandler != nil && [self.defaultHandler respondsToSelector:onerror]) {
        [self.defaultHandler performSelector:onerror withObject: error];
    }
}
if(self.logging) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Reachability test in Your Code ?

You can find [Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple Developer portal.
Link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Code:

```
 Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (internetStatus != NotReachable) {


      // Do Your Stuff As Internet Available        

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"We are unable to make a internet connection at this time. Please try again later" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];


    }
```

Comment: i have about 50 xib and implementation file in my project ,, how can i do it for the whole app ,, is it in app delegate ??

Comment: Yes You can Do it in Appdelegate `DidFinishWithLunchingoption` method.

Comment: i already put it in app delegate but when happened its crashed the app!!

Comment: Post Your Crash log then only its easy to find the issue.

Comment: Dec 21 18:22:31 iGhasss-iPhone kbd[57] <Warning>: -[TIXPCDataTransport _handleForPurpose:withReplyBlock:] couldn't get data source for purpose=__TIRDTAB

Comment: in the facebook app when the network is not available it shows a red alert in the header with label "network error" ,, i need to do somthing like that ,, do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your error and then convert in your custom error message using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method

```
NSString *str = @"server with a specified hostname could not be found";

if ([yourErrorMsg isEqualToString:str])
{
    NSString *customError = [yourErrorMsg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:str withString:@"Your Custom String"];
    NSLog(@"New custom error = %@",customError);
}
```